# Adaptive Teaching of Math Fluency

Tags: teaching, math

Looking for a game like interface that presents math facts starting at basic concepts like "1 + 1" then models the childs fluency, or lack of, and uses that data to present questions. Errors should be corrected as they're made; doesn't require an explaination, even just a error-buzz sound and a reseting of selected. Game wise it the game should present a charted preformance based on past preformance.

Open to other approaches, just believe the system above is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I am, I am, I. (It looks like you were in need of a few words. You're welcome.)

Comment: This is essentially a shopping request, and not really relevant to parenting as is.

Comment: @Beofett: Not sure why, but just got your comment. Puzzled by your take on the question since I was not looking to buy anything (shopping) -- nor do I understand how teaching math is not related to being a parent. Please reply, thanks!

Comment: @blunders I said it was "essentially" a shopping request. A shopping request in Stackexchange terms doesn't mean "I'm looking to exchange money for a product" but rather "I need something that meets these criteria; please provide recommendations that might work". This typically results in a list of answers each recommending a different product or products, and are considered [off topic for stackexchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: Regarding teaching math and its relevance to parenting... that's a very timely question!  We're currently [having](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/conversation/teaching-homeschooling-discussion) [discussions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/conversation/teaching-homeschooling-discussion-part-2) as to where the line should be drawn between "teaching" and "parenting" as it pertains to our site.  I encourage you and everyone else to hop into our [meta site](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/295/where-do-we-draw-the-line-between-teaching-and-parenting) and chime in.

Comment: +2 @Beofett: Given that there's so few "products" that do what I'm talking about, in fact none that I aware of, don't believe a long list of items is possible. Beyond that, shopping is shopping, believe you're saying the question is subjective; which again is only possible if more than one choice exist. I'll check out the meta question. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @blunders The blog I linked goes into much better detail than I could, but yes, the question is subjective, and also any answers would be too localized and subject to change (if you got a good answer, a year later that answer may be obsolete).

Comment: @Beofett: So, reviewed the blog, and unless you're able to restate the logic you used, and reference where on that page it's cited, I'm not "buying" that is question is some how formatted as a shopping question for the very reason I stated before, in order for it to be a shopping question more something has to exist which is comparable to another item that exists which meets the requirements stated. At that point I asked the question, and selected an answer, I had not tried the suggested solutions. Since then I have, and none met the stated requirements.

Comment: To me this is a does it exist question, not a how to pick from what exist question.

Comment: @blunders You are saying "I need software that does x". Whether there's one package that does it, or 50, you're requesting a list of matches. As I said before, questions that request a list of answers are off topic. Whether you intend to purchase or not has nothing to do with it being categorized as a "shopping" question, nor does the quantity or variety of answers that meet your criteria. As the blog states, even if you do get a "perfect" answer, "technology moves so rapidly that the best shopping recommendations will be utterly obsolete within a year".

Comment: @blunders If, instead, the question is "does this exist", then the possible answers would be "yes" or "no", and would therefore still not be a good question.  If you would like to discuss this further, I suggest we take it to [chat].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely try [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/)! It's free! Google and the Gates Foundation have contributed money sponsoring it. There is talk of it being translated.

- presents math drills from 1+1 to university level calculus and algebra
- supported by youtube videos explaining the concepts
- achieve badges based on proficiency
- must answer 10 questions in a row correctly in order to be considered proficient; answer incorrectly and the count starts again, badges for persistance
- must answer question correctly before continuing to next question
- success indicated with a happy or sad face (no annoying sounds if you keep getting it wrong)
- hints are available on request that present the solution step-by-step each time you request an additional hint
- progress is charted on a star chart which maps the math concepts to one another
- some reading is required; not a problem with parent support
- coach accounts (e-mail of the coach) allows tutors to follow progress

I would also recommend [Math Blaster](http://www.mathblaster.com/Parents/Default.aspx):

- arcade style game with time pressure
- different levels of difficulty
- sound and visual indication of success or failure
- questions answered incorrectly return more frequently
- kids tend to stick with it, very engaging (I don't like playing it but my kids do.)
- audio instructions, little reading required

Comment: Oh Math Blaster..... +1 for reminding me of my grade school days. :) That game was the best!

Comment: +1 @nGinius: Thanks, I'd seen Khan's videos before, but had never seen the interface for testing knowledge learned or linking the subjects. So far it's ok, not happy that the site  is not secure and sends emails/names/etc unencrypted, but guess I'll just set up dummy names/emails to try it out more.

Answer (score 0):

**I highly recommend card games.** I am convinced that this is how I got to be good at maths (and I have consistently been top of my maths classes at school).

One of the biggest advantages of this system (other than it being both fun and social) is that **it introduces a competitive element, and a direct short-term incentive to learn**. In order to win the card game, strong maths skills are needed. Furthermore, maths is learnt through practise, and I think that a child is much more likely to spend long periods of time playing a card game than doing maths exercises on a computer.

Depending on your child's level of maths (and experience with card games), you can start with pontoon (AKA blackjack or 21), and then move on to Rummy (Gin-Rummy is more fun :)) and Whist based games (German Whist is good for 2 players), or any other good card games you know that involve adding up. Other good maths-training games include Monopoly and darts.